# Pose estimation and media pipe detection on multiple people

Tags: image-processing, object-detection, yolo, mediapipe, pose-estimation

I am working on a pose estimation project and I am using mediapipe model for pose estimation, but this model only detects single human, i am thinking to use another model for ex. yolo to detect multiple humans and then crop each one and send their frame to the mediapipe one by one to do pose estimation each one, do you think that would work or theres another methodogolgy ? and if yes how ?

i tried to search i found that yolo can detect 20 people so I thought manyby this model cantake every personit detcted and send it as a single human to the media pipe model

Comment: Yep, the crop idea works. If you google something like "multi person pose estimation mediapipe" you should be able to find examples with code.